# Make some personalizations in vscode specifically for some theme

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to make some customization in vscode settings like font size and font weight specific for some theme. For e.g -> I want to do fontsize 15 for one theme but when I change to another it's fontsize should be 12, I mean for exmple :).

Comment: the theme does not control/change the font, it only change colors, so why change the font size based on the used colors.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do so is to directly change the *VSCODE* `font-size` *settings* by going to

- `File`->`Settings`->`Searching Font-size`->`Changing it` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> and doing the same process
- You could also go to [Font switcher extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=evan-buss.font-switcher) and download it and directly type <kbd>F1</kbd>->`Font size`

[image: as in here]

> And lastly, I think it seems no such feature exists for changing the font size according to the theme unless and until you are able to get very specific info such as some unique id or something about the theme you are using and apply certain code to your `settings.json` you may be able to modify it.